# Java IO readers - how do they work?

Tags: java, io, connection, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm working on project where I need to read several files from the server.
I was wondering if I can read the output and connect to somewhere else with the same instance.
Apparently I can (see below).

Tried this pseudocode:

```
c.connect(google)
BufferedReader r1 = ... c.getInputStream();

c.connect(somewhereelse)
BufferedReader r2 = ... c.getInputStream();
print(r1)
print(r2)
```

And the output was correct.

I don't know how does IO streams works or what does this conn function returns (I'll check that during winter evenings :-))

Real question: Can I rely on the fact I'll always get correct data?
i.e. Does buffered reader keep some reference to data object that is not anymore bound to connection itself?

Comment: Try it and see what happens ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer as I said: I did, but I'm not sure if it's 100%, perhaps there is some situation in which it could change and I'll have to rewrite half of an app (yes, try&fail is one way to learn, but ...)

Comment: What do you mean; which "data object"? An InputStream that you get from a connection just reads from that connection and remains bound to it. A Reader wrapped around the InputStream remains bound to the InputStream.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Then this code shouldn't work, but it does. If this would be for sure, it would be nice for me (no need to create new connections). And I'm not skilled enough to check how does this really work :-(

Comment: "Which code" shouldn't work? You haven't posted any code that could possible work. And you haven't clarified what you mean with "data object" either.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I only wrote it in pseudocode, cos I was coding on another PC and I'm too lazy :-) 
data object is that black box for me - object which is passed to InputStream - the real data. Idk how InputStream works, whether it contains any reference to file on web or it tries to read whole file (I don't think so, then buffered reader would make no sense) or it is directly connected to a low-level connection or ...
If this doesn't make any sense, please wait, I just returned from nightshift, so ... a bit tired, hard to think

Answer (score 0):

No, I think you can't trust this code. InputStream needs a connection to fetch data.
For example, if you open `java.net.SocketInputStream` (url connections use this stream) and see `read` method, you will see such code:

```
    // connection reset
    if (impl.isConnectionReset()) {
        throw new SocketException("Connection reset");
    }
```

a bit lower you can see, that stream tries to fetch buffered data if exists:

```
    /*
     * We receive a "connection reset" but there may be bytes still
     * buffered on the socket
     */
    if (gotReset) {...}
```

and lower is checking for a connections lost:

```
   /*
    * If we get here we are at EOF, the socket has been closed,
    * or the connection has been reset.
    */
    if (impl.isClosedOrPending()) {
        throw new SocketException("Socket closed");
    }
```

About your working implementation:

- First guess is that you did not close your first connection. Linking `c` to another connection did not close previous one.
- Second guess is that your data was buffered. By connection or by your buffer reader.

I could be wrong in my thoughts, but it seams to be true at first sight.